# Calling SpriteBatch.begin() and end()

Tags: java, performance, graphics, libgdx

I'm making a game in Java using libGDX. In each object's render method, SpriteBatch.begin() and SpriteBatch.end() are called. Is this a good practice? Should I only call begin() and end() in the Screen class that handles all of the rendering?

Comment: Why do you ask silly questions when there is good libGDX wiki https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-Textureregions,-and-Sprites ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not good practice, because it defeats the purpose of SpriteBatch: to batch multiple sprites into a single draw call in order to minimize the associated performance penalty of each draw call.

You should minimize the number of calls to `begin()` and `end()`, but this is only helpful if you are drawing a series of objects that all reference the same Texture (they could be TextureRegions from the same texture atlas). Every time you call `spriteBatch.draw()` with something that references a different Texture, it is the equivalent (in performance) of calling `end()` and `begin()` again. The same is true every time you call `setShader()` or `setProjectionMatrix()` or `setBlendFunction()`.

I think the cleanest way to do it is as you described. Only call `begin()` and `end()` in the Screen class. But if you are using multiple different texture atlases, you should also sort your objects' draw order to group ones that share the same Texture (or blend mode/shader/projection matrix).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll have to sort my code out to follow these guidelines.